# Package update broke video drivers

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, upgrade, kubuntu

I use Kubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) on my laptop. Three days ago, my package manager notified me of a system upgrade, which I accepted with no second thought. The next time I booted my machine, my GUI tty7 wasn't working anymore (weirdly, the Kubuntu logo still displayed on boot/halt). This was the update that caused the problem, recovered from /var/log/apt/history.log:

```
Install: primus-libs:amd64 (0~20150328-4, automatic),
         primus-libs:i386 (0~20150328-4, automatic),
         libcuda1-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, automatic),
         primus:amd64 (0~20150328-4, automatic),
         primus-libs-ia32:i386 (0~20150328-4, automatic),
         bumblebee:amd64 (3.2.1-14, automatic),
         bbswitch-dkms:i386 (0.8-4ubuntu1, automatic),
         nvidia-opencl-icd-384:amd64 (384.900ubuntu0.17.04.1, automatic),
         nvidia-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, automatic)
Upgraded: libcrack2:amd64 (2.9.2-3, 2.9.2-3ubuntu1),
          libcurl3:amd64 (7.52.1-4ubuntu1.2, 7.52.1-4ubuntu1.3),
          cracklib-runtime:amd64 (2.9.2-3, 2.9.2-3ubuntu1),
          libicu57:amd64 (57.1-5ubuntu0.1, 57.1-5ubuntu0.2),
          mysql-client-core-5.7:amd64 (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1),
          libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.16.6-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, 2.18.0-0ubuntu0.17.04.2),
          libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1),
          curl:amd64 (7.52.1-4ubuntu1.2, 7.52.1-4ubuntu1.3),
          libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.16.6-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, 2.18.0-0ubuntu0.17.04.2),
          mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1),
          libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.52.1-4ubuntu1.2, 7.52.1-4ubuntu1.3),
          nvidia-375:amd64 (375.66-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, 384.90-0ubuntu0.17.04.1),
          base-files:amd64 (9.6ubuntu13, 9.6ubuntu13.1)
Remove: libcuda1-375:amd64 (375.66-0ubuntu0.17.04.1),
        nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.8.4),
        bbswitch-dkms:amd64 (0.8-4ubuntu1),
        nvidia-opencl-icd-375:amd64 (375.66-0ubuntu0.17.04.1)
```

Well, of course it was a NVidia driver problem, I thought. So I looked for some advice for recovering/reinstalling the drivers and tried some myself, using my available console ttys. According to the apt history.log again, the apt commands used were as listed below, together with some `dpkg-reconfigure` and similar commands.

```
apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-data sddm xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-intel
apt-get install nvidia-prime:amd64=0.8.4
apt-get install bbswitch-dkms:amd64=0.8-4ubuntu1
apt-get install nvidia-opencl-icd-375
apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
apt-get install nvidia-common
apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

Now I don't even have access to console ttys anymore, only Recovery Mode. Normal boot ends in a black screen with a single underscore on top-left corner, and the system responds to no input (Esc, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+D, Ctrl+Alt+F2, nothing).

How can I fix my system? Can I recover the system to the state it was prior to the breaking upgrade to keep my system settings? (Side question, is it normal for upgrades to break things? Should I avoid upgrading driver software? Feels like a security flaw not to upgrade).